# How to create a custom endpoint in Sanity CMS?

Tags: javascript, content-management-system, sanity

I have a Sanity CMS with some data and a Gatsby frontend which fetches the data from Sanity via GraphQL. This works well in most cases but I would need a custom endpoint which gives back a document based on some arbitrary logic.

I've tried the custom plugins but I couldn't figure out how I can publish a new endpoint with them.

Answer (score 0):

The most lightweight solution is probably to install the [Dashboard tool](https://www.sanity.io/docs/dashboard) to you Studio. Briefly, what you do is

1. Install the Dashboard tool to you Studio:

```sh
sanity install @sanity/dashboard
```

2. Create a `src/dashboardConfig.js` file and make it contain the following:

```js
export default {
  widgets: [
    {
      name: 'project-info'
    },
    {
      name: 'project-users'
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Let your Studio know that you've implemented your own dashboard config by appending this to your `sanity.json` file:

```
{
  "implements": "part:@sanity/dashboard/config", 
  "path": "./dashboardConfig.js" 
}
```

Congrats, you now have a Dashboard with two Widgets in your Studio! Confirm this by running it locally and point your browser to http://localhost:3333/dashboard.

Next, you'll want to create your own widget. For a flying start, grab a skinny example which already works

```sh
sanity init plugin https://github.com/sanity-io/plugin-template-dashboard-widget-cats/archive/master.zip
```

The above `cats` Widget will be installed to the `/plugins` folder of your Studio. Go ahead and edit it (it's basically just a React component) to get the results you want. Or use it as a guideline for how to [create your own widget](https://www.sanity.io/docs/dashboard/creating-your-own-widget).

Hope this helps you out!